# Rounding down with a number. Finding the n in n.mp

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Bit of an odd question. I'm using cocoa.

I have a series of numbers e.g.:

```
0.87

0.32

1.12

2.34

8.82

12.66
```

and I want to get the bit before the decimal place, with no rounding.

Like this:

```
0.87 -> 0

0.32 -> 0

1.12 -> 1

2.34 -> 2

8.82 -> 8

12.66 -> 12
```

I can round the numbers with no problem, but I can't figure out how to just take the 'rounded down' figure in an elegant and non complicated way. Can you help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use floor(double). Or cast to an int

Answer (score 4):

Simply cast it to an `int` and you're good to go.

```
NSLog(@"n is %i", n);
```

`%i` will automatically cast it to `int`. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
float x = 0.89;
int y = x;
```

int round down automatically.